# Objective-C Property - Difference Between Retain and Assign

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

I think I am missing something about property attributes.
First, I can't understand the difference between `retain` and `assign`.

If I use `assign`, does the property increase the `retain` counter by 1 to the setter and also to the getter, and do I need to use `release` to both of them?

And how does this work with `readwrite` or `copy`? From the view of a `retain` count.

I am trying to understand when i need to use `release` after working with a property (setter and getter)

```
@property (readwrite,assign) int iVar;
```

What does `assign` do here?

What is the difference between:

```
@property (readwrite,assign) int iVar;
```

and

```
@property (readwrite,retain) int iVar;
```

and

```
@property (readwrite) int iVar;
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what is the different between : @property (readwrite,assign) int iVar; to @property (readwrite,retain) int iVar; to @property (readwrite) int iVar;

The setter for `@property (readwrite,assign) sometype aProperty;` is semantically equivalent to

```
-(void) setAProperty: (sometype) newValue
{
    ivar = newValue;
}
```

The above is more or less what you will get if you put

```
@asynthesize aProperty = ivar;
```

in your implementation.

The setter for `@property (readwrite,retain) sometype aProperty;` is semantically equivalent to

```
-(void) setAProperty: (sometype) newValue
{
    [newValue retain];
    [ivar release];
    ivar = newValue;
}
```

Clearly, it makes no sense to retain or release an int, so sometype must be either `id` or `SomeObjectiveCClass*`

The setter for `@property (readwrite,copy) sometype aProperty;` is semantically equivalent to

```
-(void) setAProperty: (sometype) newValue
{
    sometype aCopy = [newValue copy];
    [ivar release];
    ivar = aCopy;
}
```

In this case, not only must sometype be an objective C class but it must respond to `-copyWithZone:` (or equivalently, implement `NSCopying`).

If you omit retain or assign or copy, the default is assign.

By the way, I have simplified the above by not considering the locking that occurs because the properties don't also specify `nonatomic`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two kind of specifiers:

The `readwrite` specifier tells that the property will be read/write, so when you do a `@ synthesize` it will create both the getter and the setter.

There's also `readonly`, to specify that the property will only have a getter.

The other modifiers specify how the properties will behave respect of the reference counting:

The `assign` modifier, tells that the ivar will simply be assigned with whatever the setter receives. So, in case of an object, `retain` won't be called.

With `retain`, whenever you use the synthesized setter, `retain` will be called, so the object will be retained. This means that the class that has the setter needs to `release` it at some point (probably in its `dealloc` method).

As for `copy`, it means that instead of `retain`, the object will receive a `copy` message. This means that you'll end up with a copy of the original object, with a retain count of one, so again, you are responsible of releasing it.

Comment: so if i understand correct
1. readwrite just assing a pointer and return a pointer with NO change in counter?

2. when i use assing i just get pointer to the object and there is NO retain so if the object will release i will lost him?
and with retain this is not the case?

3. as for copy i understand the setter make new object with count 1, and the getter just return pointer?

And what about the getter when i used the retain attribute, i heard somthing about autorelease pointer?

Comment: I clarified my answer a bit. There are two kind of specifiers: one kind relates to how the property is access (`readwrite`, `readonly`), the other kind relates to how the property will handle memory (`assign`, `retain`, `copy`). You need to use both, and they are orthogonal (a `readwrite` property can be either `retain`, `assign` or `copy`)